# Using template to create default constructor in C++ in main

Tags: c++, templates, class-constructors

Is there a way to use templates to create a standard constructor of class in your main?

If I have a class:

#### myclass.h

```
class myClass
{
private:
    float a;
public:
    myClass(float _a) {a = _a;}
    float getA(){return a;}
    ~myClass() {}
};
```

Is there a way to template this in your main like so:

#### main.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

typedef myClass<5.0> Dummy

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // EDIT: removed the following typo
    // Dummy dummy();
    Dummy dummy;
    std::cout << dummy.getA() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which should output:

```
> 5.0000000
```

So that one may define in the main a standard way to construct the instances.

Comment: Why can't you just set default value for this argument (`myClass(float _a = 5.0) {a = _a;}`)?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why do you want to use a template for this? What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: `Dummy dummy();` This is a declaration of a function.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The idea is that you can include the class in your main and define what you want the default to be, or even define a set of default types.

Comment: @eerorika typo sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are possibly better off just using a default instance which you make copies of whenever you need a new instance:

```
#include "myclass.h"

Dummy myClass(5.0);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    myClass dummy1 = Dummy;
    std::cout << dummy1.getA() << std::endl;
    myClass dummy2 = Dummy;
    std::cout << dummy2.getA() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C++17 and Below

Unfortunately C++ does not allow you to use floating point types as non-type template parameters yet.  That said, you can fake it by accepting a numerator and denominator as integers and then doing that "math" in the class to get a floating point value.  That would look like

```
template<size_t numerator, size_t denominator = 1> // use a default value so you don't have to specify the denominator for whole values
class myClass
{
private:
    float a;
public:
    myClass(float _a = static_cast<float>(numerator) / denominator) : a(_a) {}
    float getA(){return a;}
    ~myClass() {}
};

typedef myClass<5> Dummy;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Dummy dummy; // notice this isn't Dummy dummy();.  That makes a function, not a variable
    std::cout << dummy.getA() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You could also add a default value to `numerator` if you want to so that you could do

```
// Pre C++17
myClass<> foo; 

//C++17 and later
myClass foo;
```

## C++20

Now that we can use floating point types<sup>1</sup> the code can be simplified to:

```
template<float default_value = 0.0f>
class myClass
{
private:
    float a;
public:
    myClass(float _a = default_value) : a(_a) {}
    float getA(){return a;}
    ~myClass() {}
};

typedef myClass<5.0f> Dummy;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Dummy dummy;
    std::cout << dummy.getA() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>1: no compilers actually support this yet, but it is allowed per the standard</sup>

Comment: Ouch! Integer division :)

Comment: Nice answer. But don't you need to cast numerator or denominator to float before doing a division?

Comment: @Quentin D'oh.  Fixed.

Comment: @pptaszni Yep.  Just fixed.

Comment: "Unfortunately C++ does not allow you to use floating point types as non-type template parameters." really? Is this not part of C++20 now? http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1714r1.html

Comment: @Klaus C++20 has yet to be finialized so currently the C++ tag means C++17.  This answer is answering to that standard.

Comment: My understanding is that C++20 feature list was finalized on Cologne meeting last year. Doesn't matter, currently non of the compilers support float as NTTP. :-)

Comment: @Klaus I've added what they can simplify the code to once they have a conforming C++20 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Building onto [@pptaszni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60530308/3233393), you could create a "factory factory function":

```
auto makeMyClassFactory(float value) {
    return [=] {
        return myClass{value};
    };
}

auto const Dummy = makeMyClassFactory(5.0f);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto dummy = Dummy();
    std::cout << dummy.getA() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/B9UV1IVDeLLqrQyW)

Comment: That's what I did originally, but it looked a bit messy and I wanted something that looked tidier.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but you can write a factory function (or class if it is more complicated) like this:

```
myClass createMyClassV5()
{
  return myClass(5.0);
}
```

Unfortunately, you cannot make it a template, because `float` are not allowed to be template non-type parameters. You could do it with `int` though.